# .NET 4 performance counters won't load

Tags: performance-monitor, wcf

I am using a software based on WCF services and .NET 4.6. The configuration of the WCF services (throttling, etc.) is left at the user's IT department discretion.

In order to make the most informed decision, I would like to check the performance counters for this service.

On the server (Windows Server 2012 R2), the performance counters expected (ServiceModel[Endpoint/Operation/Service] 4.0.0.0) are not there in the "Add Counters" menu, but some counters that won't load are there:

[Screenshot of perfmon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv5Ey.png)

The error message is "Can't load performance counters".

In the registry, I can see that the GUIDs of librairies that won't load match the missing libraries:

[Screenshot of regedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65875.png)

---

I do not understand what is going on here, and why the counters won't load.

I have tried to unregister and registers them again, using `(un)lodctr`, without any change.

I have tried to uninstall / install, repair, and upgrade the .NET framwork without any change.